# How do I refresh a table view from a separate uiviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my project I have two view controllers one that lists all the core data stored in a table view and a second that allows the user to input data to be stored. However when I click the back button on the navigation controller on the second it fails to refresh the `tableView`.

I have tried `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the `viewDidLoad` as a bit of a long shot but no joy.

How would i go about refreshing the data when the user clicks back?

Many thanks
Danny

Comment: put the reloadData call in viewWillAppear:

Comment: ReyGonzales is rigth, it's that simple!

Comment: as Rey Gonzales said `viewWillAppear` will be called every time view with the table shows up, instead of `viewDidLoad ` which called once.

Comment: would you place this after viewdidload ? sorry im on train atm so cant test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest route would be to move `[self.tableView reloadData]` from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear` but I would suggest using a delegate or callback so that it only reloads when necessary.